# SVG: append shapes along curved path

Tags: svg

I'm currently in a situation in which I need to append text to follow a curved path in SVG.  Our goal is to allow users to dynamically enter text that will be displayed along a curved path.  Normally I would use the [textPath method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/textPath) but the hang-up is that-- for the text to render as our designer has specified-- we need to convert the text to paths (probably using something like Opentype).  I wasn't hopeful that appending shapes to the textPath would work (it didn't) but I'm not sure where to go from here to achieve the same end.

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 1000 300"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

<defs>
 <path id="MyPath"
  d="M 100 200 
  C 200 100 300   0 400 100
  C 500 200 600 300 700 200
  C 800 100 900 100 900 100" />
</defs>

<use xlink:href="#MyPath" fill="none" stroke="red"  />

<text font-family="Verdana" font-size="42.5">
 <textPath xlink:href="#MyPath">
  <rect class="sq-1" height="50" width="50" x="0" y="0"/>
  <rect class="sq-2" height="50" width="50" x="100" y="0"/>
  <rect class="sq-3" height="50" width="50" x="200" y="0"/>
 </textPath>
</text>

<rect x="1" y="1" width="998" height="298" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
</svg>
```

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j_low/qqrz03k9/) for the above example.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/2013/10/SVG_in_OpenType/

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this in the browser - at least not built in anyway.  As I see it, your options are:

1. hope that there is a Javascript library out there that can convert a `<textPath>` to a `<path>`.  I'm not aware of any. JS doesn't have access to the font geometry or metrics. The library would have to parse fonts itself.
2. find or write a Javascript library out there that can distribute `<path>` elements along a `<path>`
3. Have a post-processing script on the server that runs the SVG through Inkscape, Illustrator etc to do the convert-to-path step.